# JSF2.0 Lifecycle

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Are there any differences in JSF2.0 life cycle as compared to JSF1.2? I see many features in JSF2.0, just wondering about life cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No change in life cycle!!

A new feature named Exception Handler is added which handles exceptions during JSF lifecycle